# nginx error log - request from unknown hosts

Tags: nginx

I am getting request from unknown hosts in nginx error.log trying to request files or requests which don't exist in the system.

Receiving below list of errors in error log,

- directory index is forbidden, client: 61.157.96.126, request: "GET http://www.haosou.com/?rands=_688651072032161501826712 HTTP/1.1", host: "www.haosou.com"
- [error] 10006#0: *67753 open() /favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 95.25.186.223,  request: "POST http://t3.proxy-checks.com/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "t3.proxy-checks.com"
- [error] 10006#0: *66849 directory index of "--" is forbidden, client: 120.132.95.89,  request: "GET http://www.qunar.com/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.qunar.com"

What could be the issue here? Do I need to make any configuration changes on my server to stop such requests? or Is it ok to receive such requests on server?

[image]